# I added a charity address to my contract and now I have two, can I remove one?

Tags: contract-development, tokens, bsc

The token in question is listed at the following url:

https://bscscan.com/address/0x3656b9d510af37b22cc1a5c904eb90855f953fbe

I had a charity address and fee address displaying

0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000

last night we used the function within our contract in BSCSCAN to add a charity address of

0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000001

and now the fee address shows

0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000001

and both addresses

0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000001

return true as the charity address, since these changes have happened we no longer are getting the tax on the transactions.

There should be 6% tax with 3% going to holders and 3% being burned, but now if you purchase the token everything is going to the wallet holder with no tax.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, is this fixable?

Answer (score 0):

The code sets a new address as charity but it doesn't remove the previous address.

```
function setAsCharityAccount(address account) external onlyOwner() {
    require(!_isCharity[account], "Account is already charity account");
    _isCharity[account] = true;
    FeeAddress = account;
}
```

If you wanted to flag the previous account as not charity you would have to modify as follows

```
    _isCharity[FeeAddress] = false; // Remove flag from previous account

    _isCharity[account] = true;
    FeeAddress = account;
```